# Closing open submenu - jQuery accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery menu and I want to be able to close a menu that is open (so that all menus are closed). The only way for it to close at the minute is to click open another menu, I've worked at it for ages and got relatively nowhere with it. Is there any way I can get the open menu to close without clicking a different menu.

Here is the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/52EH8/9/

HTML

```
<ul id="nav">
<li> <a href="#">Menu 1</a>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li> <a href="#">Menu 2</a>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 6</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 7</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 8</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 9</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Menu 3 - No Submenu</a>
</li>
<li> <a href="#">Menu 4</a>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 10</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 11</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 12</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 13</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li> <a href="#">Menu 5</a>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 14</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 15</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 16</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 17</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 18</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

jQuery

```
 function initMenu() {
 $('#nav ul').hide();
 $('#nav li a').click(

 function () {
     var checkElement = $(this).next();
     if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
         return false;
     }
     if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
         removeActiveClassFromAll();
         $(this).addClass("active");
         $('#nav ul:visible').slideToggle('normal');
         checkElement.slideToggle('normal');
         return false;
     }
 });
 }
 function removeActiveClassFromAll() {
     $('#nav li a').each(function (index) {
          $(this).removeClass("active");
      });
     }
 $(document).ready(function () {initMenu();});
```

Any help is much appreciated, Thank You.

Comment: found some flaws in the previous answer so i have re-edited the answer with some changes in the code in question also. You can alter the code or fallback to the previous code wherever you think the addition to the existing code will lead to undesired fuctionality

Comment: @UDB Thanks, Your code works great in jsfiddle, unfortunately whenever I try it out on the website (it's on wordpress) it doesn't work so well. Maybe there is something else there conflicting with it or something, it is not my site and I don't really know my way around it yet. 

But you've given me a new way of looking at it, hopefully I can figure something out from this. Thanks

Comment: which part behave differently on website?

Comment: @UDB When I click the menu it opens then immediately closes on me. I've just realised that the HTML I submitted is slightly different to the page I am testing on(e.g. the id 'nav' is in a div not a ul)... I've corrected it [here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52EH8/22/) and it doesn't affect the way your code works

Comment: A request:- For future references to this question to be helpful for other members or non-members, its a convention on stack overflow that you should  accept the most suitable answer or the answer that solved your problem

Comment: @UDB I was going to. I was just waiting til the end of the day. Which is now I suppose. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/52EH8/20/)

```
function initMenu() {
 $('#nav ul').hide();
 $('#nav li a').click(

 function () {
     var checkElement = $(this).next();
     if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
         $('#nav ul:visible').slideToggle('normal'); //EDITED:-close the menu if clicked again
     }
     if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
         removeActiveClassFromAll();
         $(this).addClass("active");
         $('#nav ul:visible').slideToggle('normal');
         checkElement.slideToggle('normal');
         return false;
     }

     //NEW CONDITION ADDED TO CLOSE ANY VISIBLE MENU WHEN MENU WITHOUT SUB MENU IS CLICKED
     if($(this).siblings('ul').length==0 && $(this).parent().parent().attr('id')=='nav')
     {

         removeActiveClassFromAll();
         $(this).addClass("active");
         $('#nav ul:visible').slideToggle('normal');

         return false;
     }
 });
}

function removeActiveClassFromAll() {
 $('#nav li a').each(function (index) {
     $(this).removeClass("active");
 });
}


$(document).ready(function () {
   initMenu();
});

//PART BELOW IS TO CLOSE TO MENU WHEN CLICK IS DETECTED ELSEWHERE ON DOCUMENT

$('#nav').click(function (e)

{
   e.stopPropagation();
})


 $(document).click(function () {
     $('#nav').children('li').each(function () {

       if ($(this).children('ul').css('display') == 'block') {
           $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('normal')
           $(this).children('a').removeClass('active')
       }
     })

 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use this code:

```
function initMenu() {
 $('#nav ul').hide();
 $('#nav li a').click(

 function () {
     var checkElement = $(this).next();
     if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
         $(this).removeClass("active");
         $('#nav ul:visible').slideToggle('normal');

         return false;
     }
     if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
         removeActiveClassFromAll();
         $(this).addClass("active");
         $('#nav ul:visible').slideToggle('normal');
         checkElement.slideToggle('normal');
         return false;
     }
 });

 $('#nav li a').click(function (index) {
     $(this).removeClass("active");
 });
}

function removeActiveClassFromAll() {
    $('#nav li a').each(function (index) {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {initMenu();});
```